# bower installing the wrong bootstrap version

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio, asp.net-core, bower

when i try to install any version of bootstrap it automatically download the latest version, inspecting the output i've found

> PATH=.\node_modules.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\git
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\Bower.cmd" install bootstrap#3.2.0 --force-latest --save

so in the repo at github they've mentioned a workaround

```
ECHO OFF
set params=%*
ECHO %params% | %WINDIR%\system32\FIND "--force-latest" >nul & 
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 (call set params=%%params:--force-latest=%%%)
@"%~dp0\node" "%~dp0\node_modules\bower\bin\bower" %params%
```

it even output that it's installing the correct version

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IROoF.png

yet it installs the latest versions (currently Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.5)

any work around to not install all the packages i need manually ?

**UPDATE 1 :**

it's not a caching problem, i've thought about that so i've tried an older version i didn't try before, it still downloaded the lastest version, i've even cleared the cached versions and still downloading the lastest version

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using bower? It looks like you are using visual studio so why no install bootstrap using nugget? just curious.

Comment: ok, so maybe I'm not following real well. I ran bower install bootstrap two different times in two different directories and it installed bootstrap 3.3.7 which is the latest version of bootstrap, according to bootstrap's web site. Even running the exact command you show in your post properly installs bootstrap v3.2. How are you installing bootstrap? From within VS, or command-line?

Comment: @PaulStoner yes from the bower interface from inside VS, no matter what version i select i end up with the 4.0.0 alpha 5

Answer (score 0):

While this issue can be very frustrating, and not necessarily an answer to your specific inquiry, might I suggest opening a command window, change your directory to the project folder and then run bower install --save bootstrap.

This should bring down the correct version and should not interfere with any paths setup in your build files.

Merely a suggestion.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding a caret fixed the issue: `"bootstrap": "3.3.0"` to `"bootstrap": "^3.3.0"`.

I think the problem is that there might be other dependencies that bower tries to resolve, and then automatically pulls the latest version, ignoring your version specification. The caret makes sure that whatever version bower pulls, is backwards compatible.